# Solve $x\left(x-1\right)y^{\prime\prime}+3xy^{\prime}+y=0$ for $0≤x<1$ with series

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve $x\left(x-1\right)y^{\prime\prime}+3xy^{\prime}+y=0$ for $0≤x< 1$

I am supposed to solve via the series method. The answer should look like this: $\begin{aligned}y\left(x\right)=A\frac{x}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}+B\frac{x}{\left(1-x\right)^{2}}\left(\ln\left(x\right)+\frac{1}{x}\right)\end{aligned},$ where $A, B$ are constants.

---

**My attempt:**
$\begin{array}{l}y'(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty na_nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n\\ y''(x)=\sum_{n=2}^\infty n(n-1)a_nx^{n-2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n\end{array}$
Substituting,
$$x(x-1)\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+2)(n+1)a_{n+2}x^n+3x\sum_{n=0}^\infty(n+1)a_{n+1}x^n+\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n=0$$
This is where I am stuck with the algebra. And I have no idea how and where to apply the condition $0≤x<1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $y'$ will be multiplied by $x$, leave it as it is:
$$xy'=\sum_{n\ge0}na_nx^n.$$
Likewise,
$$x^2y''=\sum_{n\ge0}n(n-1)a_nx^n.$$
Only $xy''$ needs a shift (but only by $1$) on indices:
$$xy''=\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)na_{n+1}x^n.$$
The coefficient of $x^n$ in your differential equation is therefore:
$$0=(n+1)((n+1)a_n-na_{n+1}),$$
i.e.
$$y=A\sum_{n\ge1}nx^n=Ax\sum_{n\ge1}nx^{n-1}=Ax\left(\frac1{1-x}\right)'=A\frac x{(1-x)^2}.$$
But this particular solution $y_0(x):=\frac x{(1-x)^2}$ is not the end of the story, since on each of the three intervals $(-\infty,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(1,+\infty)$, the space of solutions of this linear second order ODE is 2-dimensional. Writing $$y(x)=C(x)y_0(x)=\frac x{(1-x)^2}C(x),$$ you find (after some calculations) that $y(x)$ is a solution iff...

> Substituting $$y(x)=C(x)y_0(x),$$ $$y'(x)=C'(x)y_0(x)+C(x)y'_0(x),$$ $$y''(x)=C''(x)y_0(x)+2C'(x)y'_0(x)+C(x)y_0''(x)$$ and remembering that $y_0$ is a solution, the equation becomes $$x\left(x-1\right)y_0C''+\left(2x\left(x-1\right)y_0'+3xy_0\right)C'=0.$$ Replace $y'_0$ with $\frac{1+x}{x(1-x)}y_0$, so as to factor $y_0$ and cancel it.

$$x(x-1)C''+(x-2)C'=0,$$
which (after some more calculations) gives indeed the general solution:

> $$C''=\left(-\frac2x+\frac1{x-1}\right)C'$$$$C'=B\frac{x-1}{x^2}$$

$$C(x)=A+B\left(\ln|x|+\frac1x\right).$$

Comment: There are some little mistakes in the indeces of the series. If a series is multiplied by $x^2$ it can't contain elements of order $0$ or $1$

Comment: @Marco I can see no mistake. My series $x^2y''$ contains no element of order $0$ or $1$, because of the factor $n(n-1)$. Same for the factor $n$ in $xy'$ and $xy''$.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I misscalculated one of the coefficients

Comment: I don't think i understand how you arrived at the last two equations (especially the last one)?

Answer (score 2):

Try to put everything under the same sum and then you can identify the expression of $a_n$

$$\sum_{n\ge0}n(n-1)a_nx^n -\sum_{n\ge0}(n+1)na_{n+1}x^n + 3 \sum_{n\ge0}n a_nx^n + \sum_{n\ge0}a_nx^n = 0 $$

Using uniqueness :

$$n(n-1)a_n - (n+1)na_{n+1} + 3na_n + a_n = 0$$
$$(n(n-1) + 3n + 1))a_n= (n+1)na_{n+1}$$
$$(n+1) a_n= na_{n+1}$$
$${(n+1) \over n }a_n= a_{n+1}$$

Convergence radius is $$+\infty$$ with d’Alembert criterion

Then by induction
$$a_n = {n! \over (n-1)!} a_1 = na_1$$

Thus $$y(x) = \sum_{n\ge0} na_1x^n = a_1 {x \over (1-x)^2}$$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Sorry for that I don’t have enough reputation to put comment

Comment: Then what about waiting until you do have enough reputation?

Comment: don’t want me to help I guess..